# SKPaymentQueue canMakePayments return NO on 4.3 simulator

Tags: iphone, return, simulator, in-app

When I apply  [SKPaymentQueue canMakePayments] on SDK 5.0 Simulator it return YES. When ever I try on SDK 4.3 Simulator it returns NO.

Any idea?

Comment: InApp is possible in simulator in case of ios 5.0 only

Comment: I want to believe so! But I could not find any official documentation for that assumption.